# Add items and remove items from cart using jQuery. I am not able to remove items added using jQuery only. Method-1 in script.js file

Tags: jquery

Hi, I am making a simple cart in which I can add or remove item using jQuery. Using method-2 in the script code i am able to do this but on using method-1 i am able to remove only list items which are added in default HTML. but same not working for list items added using jQuery.

> Please tell me why method - 1 is not working for elements added using jQuery. 
>   Please also describe how both methods are different in this condition and in general.

Hope my doubt is clear to you, 
Thanks and Regards for your responses and efforts

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 // counter to recognize new item in the list
 var itemId = 1;

 // add items to the list
   $("form").submit ( function (event){
     var txt = document.createElement("li");
     var btn = document.createElement("button");
     txt.id = 'item-' + itemId;
    btn.id = 'delete-'+ itemId;
    btn.className = 'item-button bg-light';
    txt.className = 'm-1';
    txt.innerHTML = $("input").val() + ' '; 
    btn.innerHTML = '&#10060;';
    $(txt).append(btn);
    $("ul").append(txt); 
    $("input").val('');
    itemId ++;
    event.preventDefault();
   });


   // method-1 to remove the items from the list // *Not working for only elements added using jQuery
   $("ul .item-button").click ( function(){
     $(this).parent().remove();
   });

   // method-2 to remove the items from the list
   //$('ul').on('click', '.item-button', function() {
   //  $(this).parent().remove();
  //});

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>My Shopping Cart</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5048f8c666.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container mt-3">
  <div>
   <form id="form1">
    <input type="text" id="inputItem" placeholder="Enter the Product" required>
    <button type="submit" id="btn1">add</button>
   </form>
  </div>
  <div>
   <h4>Items Available in the cart</h4>
   <ul id="Items">
    <li id="item-00">list item <button id="delete-00" class="item-button">&#10060;</button></li>
    <li id="item-0">list item <button id="delete-0" class="item-button">&#10060;</button></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check out the answer,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to target document instead of the class.

Change this:

```
 $("ul .item-button").click ( function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
   });
```

Into this:

```
   $(document).on('click',"ul .item-button",function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
   });
```

Because the new items are created after your code executed, so they will not have the function attached to them.

But this way, i assume that the function is listening to the document and find the target from parameter which is "ul .item-button" and execute for it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 // counter to recognize new item in the list
 var itemId = 1;

 // add items to the list
   $("form").submit ( function (event){
     var txt = document.createElement("li");
     var btn = document.createElement("button");
     txt.id = 'item-' + itemId;
    btn.id = 'delete-'+ itemId;
    btn.className = 'item-button bg-light';
    txt.className = 'm-1';
    txt.innerHTML = $("input").val() + ' '; 
    btn.innerHTML = '&#10060;';
    $(txt).append(btn);
    $("ul").append(txt); 
    $("input").val('');
    itemId ++;
    event.preventDefault();
   });


   $(document).on('click',"ul .item-button", function(){
     $(this).parent().remove();
   });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>My Shopping Cart</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5048f8c666.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container mt-3">
  <div>
   <form id="form1">
    <input type="text" id="inputItem" placeholder="Enter the Product" required>
    <button type="submit" id="btn1">add</button>
   </form>
  </div>
  <div>
   <h4>Items Available in the cart</h4>
   <ul id="Items">
    <li id="item-00">list item <button id="delete-00" class="item-button">&#10060;</button></li>
    <li id="item-0">list item <button id="delete-0" class="item-button">&#10060;</button></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```